# Android Adding 3rd party framework

Tags: android, frameworks, makefile, package-managers

I am trying to add a 3rd party framework into vanilla Android code. After that I made an application which uses this framework to run(Some UI customizations).

After building and flashing this android code  my application is not installed on the device(but the apk is generated  via code build). Package manager is not installing the Apk as it is not able to find the 3rd party framework/libraries which are used in this app.

Any possible linking that should be done and I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Load the relevant classes using the current classloader, and use Java Reflection to call the appropriate methods

```
Class myClass = getClassLoader().loadClass("com.myclass.CustomFramework")l
```